# Is it possible for a for loop to crash a code despite it having no contents

Tags: c, function, variables, for-loop, runtime-error

In my code I had an error that I was able to pinpoint down to a certain for loop, but now I'm uncertain as to how exactly the problem is being caused

```
int linregm(int n, float x[], float y[]){
float denom=1;
sumx = 0.0;                  
sumx2 = 0.0;                    
sumxy = 0.0;                     
sumy = 0.0;                      
    /*
for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    { 
    //sumx  = sumx + x[i];       
    //sumx2 = sumx2 + x[i]*x[i];  
    //sumxy = sumxy + x[i] * y[i];
    //sumy  = sumy + y[i];         
} 
    */
denom = (n * sumx2 - sqr(sumx));
if (denom == 0) {
    // singular matrix. can't solve the problem.
    pass=1;
            return 0;
}

m = (n * sumxy  -  sumx * sumy) / denom;

pass=0; 
    return m;
}
```

This is the function that has a problem at the spot where there is a for-loop, even if I just run the loop itself without the internal contents it still gives me an error.

```
m = linregm(sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0]), x, y);

__IO float Send_float_Data[256];
float x[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
float y[8];
float m,b;
unsigned int pass;
float   sumx,sumx2,sumxy,sumy=0.0; 

unsigned int i=0,j;
```

And these are the variable declarations.

I'm new to C so I don't know if there are special interactions between variables or something that could have screwed up my code, there was no compiler warning so syntax shouldn't be a problem.Do you guys have any idea on what exactly I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Where are you declaring your variables? In the main-function? And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Yes, it is.  If whatver code was in the loop modified data and so prevented a different error from occurring, then removing the loop body may stop one error and surface another:(

Comment: posting code fragments, such as this question is doing, will quickly result in the question being 'closed' as 'off topic'.  Your question states the code cleanly compiles. so post a [mcve] so we can help you.